# Loading the component on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working with Single-Page App on React, and I got a problem with function so it takes some time to return the results and render it. With that I want to ask if I can change it as asynchronous function to get the result after it returns, but other components would not stuck as well.

I may misunderstand how it should work but here is the basic example of my problem:

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: "whatever"
  }

  myHeavyFunction(data){
    //while this function works whole page on browser freezes for 3-5 second
    return (<div>{result}</div>);
  }

  buttonClicked(){
    this.setState({data: "new whatever"});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.myHeavyFunction(this.state.data)}</div>
    );
  }

}
```

I didn't use any API request, it's just a function which works with big data.
In my case "myHeavyFunction" is a different component and I've tried to use React.lazy/Suspense but unfortunately it loads only when you refresh the page.

So I want the function which renders asynchronously with loading spinner after I click the button so the page doesn't refreshes and other components wouldn't freeze.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `myHeavyFunction` to return a Promise and within any handler you can either use a Promise-chain, or make the handler an `async` function and await the return value. Couple this with some "loading" state and you can display a loading indicator.

```
class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    data: "whatever",
    loading: false, // <-- loading state
  };

  myHeavyFunction = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("new whatever"), 5000); // <-- "expensive cmoputation"
    });
  };

  buttonClicked = async () => { // <-- async function
    this.setState({
      loading: true // <-- loading true
    });
    const data = await this.myHeavyFunction(); // await expensive computation
    this.setState({
      data,
      loading: false // <-- loading false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{loading ? "loading..." : data}</div> // <-- conditional render
        <button onClick={this.buttonClicked}>Update</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Async UI]

Comment: I agree with the loading indidcator part. For the second part, is it because making it return a promise takes it off the event loop, making it not to block it?

Comment: @Selçuk Basically, yes. It offloads it from the main thread and thus doesn't block it.

Comment: But is not JavaScript single threaded. The thread you mean is somehow different, right? Does it mean just off the event loop?

Comment: @Selçuk JS is single threaded, yes, but this places code/callbacks/etc *into* the queue that is processed by the event loop so it is non-blocking.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it sounds like the event loop is actually apart from the js thread, gonna need to read about it more.